# WPF: Commands and ViewModels relation in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to call the same command from two different view models, but I got stuck while designing them (both command and view models).

First, I created a `ViewModel1` view model class:

```
public class ViewModel1 : DependencyObject
{
    ...

    // The command property
    public ProcessMyString ProcessMyStringCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel1()
    {
        // Command gets instantiated 
        this.ProcessMyStringCommand = new ProcessMyString(this);
    }

    internal void ProcessMyString()
    {
        // This is where the actual processing method is called
        // somewhere from the business logic...
        ...
    }
```

And the `ProcessMyString` command class:

```
public class ProcessMyString : ICommand
{
    private ViewModel1 viewModel;

    public ProcessMyString(ViewModel1 viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        viewModel.ProcessMyString();
    }
}
```

Then, I created the second view model class `ViewModel2`, but when I realized that this view model **will also need to use the same command**, the command's constructor

```
public ProcessMyString(ViewModel1 viewModel)
```

will not work because it takes `ViewModel1` parameter and I need to be able to pass both view models. Then, I decided to create `ViewModelBase` class, and to make both view models extend from it. I modified the command's constructor as well, of course:

```
// Constructor's parameter is now ViewModelBase
public ProcessMyString(ViewModelBase viewModel)
```

But that meant that command's method `Execute(object parameter)` called a method from `ViewModelBase` now. That is not a good appproach because ViewModel's calls for `ProcessMyString()` should be *reserved* for `ViewModel1` and `ViewModel2` classes only. If I had class `ViewModel3` I wouldn't want it to call `ProcessMyString()` and if I don't  extend it from the `ViewModelBase` that would be fine.

**But what happens if I need a command that is shared between `ViewModel2` and `ViewModel3`?**

The summation question is: How should I organize my commands and view models to be able to make the view models share the same commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post this answer with the assumption that the `ProcessMyString` class is unnecessary and should be replaced by a generic command.

First of all, download the library [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com).
After that unpack it somewhere and add reference to this library:

> (folder with the library)\Mvvm Light
>   Toolkit\Binaries\WPF4\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll

It contains the `RelayCommand` class which is that what you need.

At first create a base class which contains your command:

```
public abstract class ProcessStringViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    // The command property
    public RelayCommand ProcessMyStringCommand { get; set; }
}
```

I would remove the inheritance from the `DependencyObject` class, but maybe you use it somehow, so let it be.

The `ViewModel1` class can be rewritten in this way:

```
public class ViewModel1 : ProcessStringViewModel
{
    public ViewModel1()
    {
        // Command gets instantiated 
        this.ProcessMyStringCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.ProcessMyString());
    }

    internal void ProcessMyString()
    {
    }
}
```

The `ViewModel2` class can call a different function, but the command is the same:

```
public class ViewModel2 : ProcessStringViewModel
{
    public ViewModel2()
    {
        this.ProcessMyStringCommand = new RelayCommand(SomeOtherFunction);
    }

    private void SomeOtherFunction()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Call of some function");
    }
}
```

If you decide to not use the base class and inheritance - you can remove the base class, copy the property to each derived class, and it will work.

Comment: If I use MVVM Light, what happens if I want to design command's `CanExecute` method? It is possible with this framework? (I have a bunch of other commands that actually have some content in `CanExecute` and not always return `true` as shown in my `ProcessMyString` command.)

Comment: @Boris Yes, it is possible and this delegate is passed as the second parameter. I haven't passed anything in my example and it has the implicit value `() => true`. Also the MVVM Light has another command class which use the CommandParameter. You can check it yourself after you download this framework.

Answer (score 7):

First off, just as a personal preference, I tend to minimize the amount of inheritance I use with my ViewModel's.  Complex UI code in non-trivial applications can be tricky enough to follow by anyone besides the original author, the last thing you want to do is make it harder by including a complex object model.

The beauty of WPF using the ICommand interface is that you should be able to favor a more compositional approach, rather an an inheritance model, and use an interface to share common properties.

Here's just a quick run-down of how I might approach this scenario:

```
public class ProcessStringCommand : ICommand
{
   private readonly IProcessStringViewModel m_viewModel;

   public ProcessStringCommand(IProcessStringViewModel vm)
   {
      m_viewModel = vm;
   }

   public void Execute(object param)
   {
      ProcessString(m_viewModel.ProcessString);
   }

   public bool CanExecute(object param)
   { 
      return true; 
   }

   private void ProcessString(string processString)
   {
      // Put logic here
   }
}

public interface IProcessStringViewModel
{
   public string ProcessString { get; }
}

public class ViewModel1 : ViewModelBase, IProcessStringViewModel
{
   private readonly ICommand m_command;
   private readonly string m_processString;

   public ViewModel1()
   {
      m_command = new ProcessStringCommand(this);
   }

   public string ProcessString
   {
      get { return m_processString; }
   }

   public ICommand ProcessStringCommand
   {
      get { return m_command; }
   }
}

public class ViewModel2 : ViewModelBase, IProcessStringViewModel
{
   private readonly ICommand m_command;
   private readonly string m_processString;       

   public ViewModel2()
   {
      m_command = new ProcessStringCommand(this);
   }

   public string ProcessString
   {
      get { return m_processString; }
   }

   public ICommand ProcessStringCommand
   {
      get { return m_command; }
   }
}

public class ViewModel3 : ViewModelBase
{
   // Whatever you need here.
}
```

Comment: this is very nice and neat. I will go with MVVM Light framework for now, as it offers so much. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  Just as an aside, I don't think the two solutions are mutually exclusive.  The framework offers some common functionality that is shared across many applications, whereas my response deals more with the overall structure of the application.  So I think you can benefit from both.  Either way, it sounds like you're on the right track.  Good luck!

Comment: I couldn't agree more regarding your observation that the two solutions are not mutually exclusive. I am anxious to dive into all this. All the best..

Comment: If the return type of `Execute` is `void` then how are you returning `return ProcessString(m_viewModel.ProcessString)` ?